# Update the default DiscussionBoard alert template

Tags: alert, email-templates

I am following in the path of many - and attempting to change the OOTB alerts.

I have created a copy of the alerttemplates.xml, and made changes to the SPAlertTemplateType.DiscussionBoard AlertTemplate (both Digest and Immediate). I added a new link, and some static text.

I copied the new file to the server and ran STSADM -o updatealerttemplates -url url -filename name_of_working_copy then ran IISReset and restarted the SharePoint Timer service.

The changes I have made do not show up in the discussion board alerts.

After reading several other threads, I even manually removed all my alert subscriptions and re-subscribed. Still no change in the alert.

NOTE - I am not creating a new custom alert, but modifying the existing one.

Code:

```
<AlertTemplate Type="List"  Name="SPAlertTemplateType.DiscussionBoard">
    <EventTypes IsVisible="True"/>
    <Format>
        <Digest>
            <Header>
                <HTML>
                    <![CDATA[
                    <html dir = $Resources:core,PageDirection;>
                    <head>
                        <base href="]]></HTML><GetVar Name="SiteUrl" URLEncodeAsURL="TRUE" /><HTML><![CDATA[">
                        <style>
                        </style>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        <table class="headertop1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="headercontent">
                                    <table class="breadcrumb" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%"><tr><td><a href="]]></HTML>
                                    <GetVar Name="SiteUrl" URLEncodeAsURL="TRUE" />
                                    <HTML><![CDATA[">]]></HTML><GetVar Name="SiteName"/>
                                    <HTML><![CDATA[</a></td><tr></table>]]></HTML>
                                    <GetVar Name="ListName" HTMLEncode="True" />
                                    <Switch>
                                        <Expr><GetVar Name="AlertFrequency"/></Expr>
                                        <Case Value="1"><HTML><![CDATA[$Resources:Alerts_dailysummary;]]></HTML></Case>
                                        <Case Value="2"><HTML><![CDATA[$Resources:Alerts_weeklysummary;]]></HTML></Case>
                                    </Switch>
                                    <HTML><![CDATA[
                                        </td></tr>
                                    </table>
                                    <table class="content" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="5">
                                                <table class="toolbar" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"><tr><td>
                                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td class="toolbarbutton">]]></HTML>
                                                            <HTML><![CDATA[<a href="]]></HTML> <GetVar Name="MySubsUrl" URLEncodeAsURL="TRUE"/>
                                                            <HTML><![CDATA[">$Resources:Alerts_link_modify;</a>]]></HTML>
                                                            <HTML><![CDATA[<a href="siteSettings"></a></td>
                                                            <td class="toolbarsep">|</td>
                                                            <td class="toolbarbutton"><a href="]]></HTML>
                                                            <GetVar Name="ListUrl" URLEncodeAsURL="TRUE"/>
                                                            <HTML><![CDATA[">$Resources:Alerts_link_view; ]]></HTML>
                                                            <GetVar Name="ListName" HTMLEncode="TRUE"/>
                                                            <HTML><![CDATA[</a></td><td class="toolbarsep">|</td>
                                                            <td class="toolbarbutton"><a href="]]></HTML><GetVar Name="ListUrl" URLEncodeAsURL="TRUE"/>
                                                            <HTML><![CDATA[/Threaded.aspx?RootFolder=]]></HTML><GetVar Name="FolderUrl" URLEncodeAsURL="FALSE"/>
                                                            <HTML><![CDATA[">View Discussion Thread</a></td>]]></HTML>
                                                            <Switch>
                                                                <Expr><GetVar Name="MobileUrl"/></Expr>
                                                                    <Case Value = "NULL"/>
                                                                    <Default>
                                                                        <HTML><![CDATA[
                                                            <td class="toolbarsep">|</td>
                                                            <td class="toolbarbutton"><a href="]]></HTML><GetVar Name="MobileUrl" />
                                                                        <HTML><![CDATA[">$Resources:Alerts_mobile_view;</a></td>]]></HTML>
                                                                    </Default>
                                                            </Switch>
                                                        <HTML><![CDATA[
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="vh" colspan="2">$Resources:Alerts_event_title;</td>
                                    <td class="vh">$Resources:Alerts_event_modified;</td>
                                    <td class="vh">$Resources:Alerts_event_modifiedby;</td>
                                    <td class="vh">&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="5" class="rulerow">&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                            ]]>
                        </HTML>
            </Header>
            <HeaderFieldsHeader>
                <HTML><![CDATA[]]></HTML>
            </HeaderFieldsHeader>
            <HeaderFields>
                <HTML><![CDATA[]]></HTML>
            </HeaderFields>
            <HeaderFieldsFooter>
                <HTML><![CDATA[]]></HTML>
            </HeaderFieldsFooter>
    <RowHeader>
        <Switch>
            <Expr><GetVar Name="AltRow"/></Expr>
            <Case Value="alt"><SetVar Name="AltRow" Scope = "Request"></SetVar></Case>
            <Default><SetVar Name="AltRow" Scope = "Request">alt</SetVar></Default>
        </Switch>
        <HTML><![CDATA[
        <tr>
        ]]></HTML>
        <Switch>
        <Expr><GetVar Name="EventType"/></Expr>
        <Case Value="1">
            <SetVar Name="LabelClass" Scope = "Request">digestlabel</SetVar>
            <SetVar Name="TdClass" Scope = "Request">vb</SetVar>
        </Case>
        <Case Value="4">
            <SetVar Name="LabelClass" Scope = "Request">deletedlabel</SetVar>
            <SetVar Name="TdClass" Scope = "Request">deleted</SetVar>
        </Case>
        <Default>
            <SetVar Name="LabelClass" Scope = "Request">digestlabel</SetVar>
            <SetVar Name="TdClass" Scope = "Request">vb</SetVar>
        </Default>
        </Switch>
        <SetVar Name="LabelClass" Scope = "Request"><GetVar Name="AltRow"/><GetVar Name="LabelClass"/></SetVar>
        <SetVar Name="TdClass" Scope = "Request"><GetVar Name="AltRow"/><GetVar Name="TdClass"/></SetVar>
        <SetVar Name="ItemNamePart" Scope="Request">
        <IfEqual>
        <Expr1><GetVar Name="EventType"/></Expr1>
        <Expr2><HTML>4</HTML></Expr2>
        <Then><GetVar Name="ItemName" HTMLEncode="TRUE"/></Then>
        <Else>
            <HTML><![CDATA[<A href="]]></HTML>
            <GetVar Name="ItemUrl" URLEncodeAsURL="TRUE"/>
            <HTML><![CDATA[">]]></HTML>
            <GetVar Name="ItemName" HTMLEncode="TRUE"/>
            <HTML><![CDATA[</A>]]></HTML>
        </Else>
        </IfEqual>
        </SetVar>
        <HTML><![CDATA[
        <td class="]]></HTML><GetVar Name="LabelClass"/><HTML><![CDATA[" colspan="2" >]]></HTML>
        <GetVar Name="ItemNamePart" />
        <HTML><![CDATA[</td>
        <td class="]]></HTML><GetVar Name="TdClass"/><HTML><![CDATA[">]]></HTML>
        <GetVar Name="TimeLastModified" HTMLEncode="TRUE" />
        <HTML><![CDATA[</td>
        <td class="]]></HTML><GetVar Name="TdClass"/><HTML><![CDATA[">]]></HTML>
        <GetVar Name="ModifiedBy" HTMLEncode="TRUE" />
        <HTML><![CDATA[ </td> 
        <td nowrap class="]]></HTML><GetVar Name="TdClass"/><HTML><![CDATA[">]]></HTML>    
        <Switch>
        <Expr><GetVar Name="EventType"/></Expr>
        <Case Value="1">
            <HTML><![CDATA[<span class="newicon">$Resources:Alerts_event_new;</span>]]></HTML>
        </Case>
        <Case Value="4">
            <HTML><![CDATA[<span class="deletedicon">$Resources:Alerts_event_deleted;</span>]]></HTML>
        </Case>
        <Default>
            <HTML><![CDATA[<span class="editedicon">$Resources:Alerts_event_edited;</span>]]></HTML>
        </Default>
        </Switch>
        <HTML><![CDATA[</td></tr>]]></HTML>
    </RowHeader>
    <RowFields>
    <Switch>
    <Expr><GetVar Name="EventType"/></Expr>
    <Case Value="2">
        <IfEqual>
            <Expr1><GetVar Name="OldValue#{Field}"/></Expr1>
            <Expr2><GetVar Name="NewValue#{Field}"/></Expr2>
            <Then>
            </Then>
            <Else>
                <HTML><![CDATA[
    <tr>
    <td class="]]></HTML><GetVar Name="LabelClass"/><HTML><![CDATA["> <div class="nobr">]]></HTML>
                <GetVar Name="DisplayName#{Field}" HTMLEncode="TRUE" />
                <HTML><![CDATA[</div></td>
    <td class="]]></HTML><GetVar Name="TdClass"/><HTML><![CDATA["><span class="digesttext">]]></HTML>
    <HTML><![CDATA[<span class="edited"> ]]></HTML>
                <Limit Len="255" AutoHyperLinkNoEncoding="TRUE" MoreText="..."><GetVar Name="OldValue#{Field}" /></Limit>
                <HTML><![CDATA[</span> ]]></HTML>
                <GetVar Name="NewValue#{Field}"/>
                <HTML><![CDATA[ </span></td>
    <td class="]]></HTML><GetVar Name="TdClass"/><HTML><![CDATA[">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="]]></HTML><GetVar Name="TdClass"/><HTML><![CDATA[">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="]]></HTML><GetVar Name="TdClass"/><HTML><![CDATA[">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>]]></HTML>
            </Else>
        </IfEqual>
    </Case>
    <Case Value="4">
        <HTML><![CDATA[
    <tr>
    <td class="]]></HTML><GetVar Name="TdClass"/><HTML><![CDATA["> <div class="nobr">]]></HTML>
        <GetVar Name="DisplayName#{Field}" HTMLEncode="TRUE" />
        <HTML><![CDATA[</div></td>
    <td class="]]></HTML><GetVar Name="TdClass"/><HTML><![CDATA[">]]></HTML>
        <GetVar Name="NewValue#{Field}" />
        <HTML><![CDATA[</td>
    <td class="]]></HTML><GetVar Name="AltRow"/><HTML><![CDATA[vb">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="]]></HTML><GetVar Name="AltRow"/><HTML><![CDATA[vb">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="]]></HTML><GetVar Name="AltRow"/><HTML><![CDATA[vb">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>]]></HTML>             
    </Case>
    <Default>
        <HTML><![CDATA[
    <tr>
    <td class="]]></HTML><GetVar Name="TdClass"/><HTML><![CDATA["> <div class="nobr">]]></HTML>
        <GetVar Name="DisplayName#{Field}" HTMLEncode="TRUE" />
        <HTML><![CDATA[</div></td>
    <td class="]]></HTML><GetVar Name="TdClass"/><HTML><![CDATA["><span class="digesttext">]]></HTML>
        <GetVar Name="NewValue#{Field}" />
        <HTML><![CDATA[</span></td>
    <td class="]]></HTML><GetVar Name="TdClass"/><HTML><![CDATA[">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="]]></HTML><GetVar Name="TdClass"/><HTML><![CDATA[">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="]]></HTML><GetVar Name="TdClass"/><HTML><![CDATA[">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>]]></HTML>
    </Default>     
    </Switch>
    </RowFields>
    <RowFooter>
    <HTML><![CDATA[]]></HTML>
    </RowFooter>
    <Footer><HTML><![CDATA[
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>]]></HTML>
    </Footer>
    </Digest>
    <Immediate>
    <Subject>
    <GetVar Name="AlertTitle" />
    <HTML><![CDATA[ - ]]></HTML>
    <GetVar Name="ItemName" />
    </Subject>
    <Header>
    <HTML><![CDATA[
    <html  dir = $Resources:core,PageDirection;>
    <head>
    <base href="]]></HTML><GetVar Name="SiteUrl" URLEncodeAsURL="TRUE" /><HTML><![CDATA[">
    <style>
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table class="headertop1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr><td class="headercontent">
    <table class="breadcrumb" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%"><tr><td><a href="]]></HTML>
    <GetVar Name="SiteUrl" URLEncodeAsURL="TRUE" />
    <HTML><![CDATA[">]]></HTML><GetVar Name="SiteName"/>
    <HTML><![CDATA[</a></td></tr></table>]]></HTML>
    <Switch>
    <Expr><GetVar Name="EventType"/></Expr>
    <Default>
        <IfSubString>
            <Expr1>0x0107</Expr1>
            <Expr2><GetVar Name="RawValue#ContentTypeId" /></Expr2>
            <Then>
    <HTML><![CDATA[ $Resources:Alerts_discussion_change1_BEGIN;]]></HTML>
            </Then>
            <Else>
    <HTML><![CDATA[ $Resources:Alerts_change1_BEGIN;]]></HTML>
            </Else>
        </IfSubString>
    </Default>
    <Case Value = "1">
        <IfSubString>
            <Expr1>0x0107</Expr1>
            <Expr2><GetVar Name="RawValue#ContentTypeId" /></Expr2>
            <Then>
    <HTML><![CDATA[ $Resources:Alerts_discussion_change0_BEGIN;]]></HTML>
            </Then>
            <Else>
    <HTML><![CDATA[ $Resources:Alerts_change0_BEGIN;]]></HTML>
            </Else>
        </IfSubString>
    </Case>
    <Case Value = "4">
        <IfSubString>
            <Expr1>0x0107</Expr1>
            <Expr2><GetVar Name="RawValue#ContentTypeId" /></Expr2>
            <Then>
    <HTML><![CDATA[ $Resources:Alerts_discussion_change4_BEGIN;]]></HTML>
            </Then>
            <Else>
    <HTML><![CDATA[ $Resources:Alerts_change4_BEGIN;]]></HTML>
            </Else>
        </IfSubString>
    </Case>
    <Case Value = "9"><HTML><![CDATA[ $Resources:Alerts_change5_BEGIN;]]></HTML></Case>
    <Case Value = "16"><HTML><![CDATA[ $Resources:Alerts_change6_BEGIN;]]></HTML></Case>
    <Case Value = "32"><HTML><![CDATA[ $Resources:Alerts_change7_BEGIN;]]></HTML></Case>
    <Case Value = "64"><HTML><![CDATA[ $Resources:Alerts_change8_BEGIN;]]></HTML></Case>
    <Case Value = "128"><HTML><![CDATA[ $Resources:Alerts_change9_BEGIN;]]></HTML></Case>
    <Case Value = "256"><HTML><![CDATA[ $Resources:Alerts_change10_BEGIN;]]></HTML></Case>
    </Switch>
    <HTML><![CDATA[<em>]]></HTML>
    <GetVar Name="ItemName" HTMLEncode="TRUE"/>
    <HTML><![CDATA[</em>]]></HTML>
    <Switch>
    <Expr><GetVar Name="EventType"/></Expr>
    <Default>
        <IfSubString>
            <Expr1>0x0107</Expr1>
            <Expr2><GetVar Name="RawValue#ContentTypeId" /></Expr2>
            <Then>
    <HTML><![CDATA[ $Resources:Alerts_discussion_change1_END;]]></HTML>
            </Then>
            <Else>
    <HTML><![CDATA[ $Resources:Alerts_change1_END;]]></HTML>
            </Else>
        </IfSubString>
    </Default>
    <Case Value = "1">
        <IfSubString>
            <Expr1>0x0107</Expr1>
            <Expr2><GetVar Name="RawValue#ContentTypeId" /></Expr2>
            <Then>
    <HTML><![CDATA[ $Resources:Alerts_discussion_change0_END;]]></HTML>
            </Then>
            <Else>
    <HTML><![CDATA[ $Resources:Alerts_change0_END;]]></HTML>
            </Else>
        </IfSubString>
    </Case>
    <Case Value = "4">
        <IfSubString>
            <Expr1>0x0107</Expr1>
            <Expr2><GetVar Name="RawValue#ContentTypeId" /></Expr2>
            <Then>
    <HTML><![CDATA[ $Resources:Alerts_discussion_change4_END;]]></HTML>
            </Then>
            <Else>
    <HTML><![CDATA[ $Resources:Alerts_change4_END;]]></HTML>
            </Else>
        </IfSubString>
    </Case>
    <Case Value = "9"><HTML><![CDATA[ $Resources:Alerts_change5_END;]]></HTML></Case>
    <Case Value = "16"><HTML><![CDATA[ $Resources:Alerts_change6_END;]]></HTML></Case>
    <Case Value = "32"><HTML><![CDATA[ $Resources:Alerts_change7_END;]]></HTML></Case>
    <Case Value = "64"><HTML><![CDATA[ $Resources:Alerts_change8_END;]]></HTML></Case>
    <Case Value = "128"><HTML><![CDATA[ $Resources:Alerts_change9_END;]]></HTML></Case>
    <Case Value = "256"><HTML><![CDATA[ $Resources:Alerts_change10_END;]]></HTML></Case>
    </Switch>
    <HTML><![CDATA[
    </td>
    </tr></table>  
    <table class="content" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">]]></HTML>
    <HTML><![CDATA[
    <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
    <table class="toolbar" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%"><tr><td>
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tr>
    <td class="toolbarbutton"><a href="]]></HTML>
    <GetVar Name="MySubsUrl" URLEncodeAsURL="TRUE"/>
    <HTML><![CDATA[">$Resources:Alerts_link_modify;</a></td>
    <td class="toolbarsep">|</td>]]></HTML>
    <Switch>
        <Expr><GetVar Name="EventType"/></Expr>
        <Default>
            <HTML><![CDATA[
    <td class="toolbarbutton"><a href="]]></HTML><GetVar Name="ItemUrl" URLEncodeAsURL="TRUE" />
            <HTML><![CDATA[">$Resources:Alerts_link_view; ]]></HTML><GetVar Name="ItemName" HTMLEncode="TRUE" /> <HTML><![CDATA[</a></td>
    <td class="toolbarsep">|</td>
    <td class="toolbarbutton"><a href="]]></HTML><GetVar Name="ListUrl" URLEncodeAsURL="TRUE"/>
    <HTML><![CDATA[/Flat.aspx?RootFolder=]]></HTML><GetVar Name="FolderUrl" URLEncodeAsURL="TRUE"/>
    <HTML><![CDATA[">View Discussion Thread</a></td>
    <td class="toolbarsep">|</td>]]></HTML>
        </Default>
        <Case Value = "4"><HTML><![CDATA[]]></HTML></Case>
    </Switch>
        <HTML><![CDATA[
    <td class="toolbarbutton"><a href="]]></HTML><GetVar Name="ListUrl" URLEncodeAsURL="TRUE" />
        <HTML><![CDATA[">$Resources:Alerts_link_view; ]]></HTML><GetVar Name="ListName" HTMLEncode="TRUE" /> <HTML><![CDATA[</a></td>]]></HTML>     
    <Switch>
    <Expr><GetVar Name="MobileUrl"/></Expr>
        <Case Value = "NULL"/>
        <Default>
            <HTML><![CDATA[
    <td class="toolbarsep">|</td>
    <td class="toolbarbutton"><a href="]]></HTML><GetVar Name="MobileUrl" />
            <HTML><![CDATA[">$Resources:Alerts_mobile_view;</a></td>]]></HTML>
        </Default>
    </Switch>
    <HTML><![CDATA[ 
    </tr>
    </table>
    </td></tr></table>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td colspan="3"class="spacer"> &nbsp;</td></tr>]]></HTML>
    </Header>
    <HTML><![CDATA[
    <tr><td colspan="3" class="rulerow">&nbsp;</td></tr>
    ]]></HTML>
    <Fields>
    <Switch>
    <Expr><GetVar Name="EventType"/></Expr>
    <Case Value="2">
    <HTML><![CDATA[
    <tr>
    <td class="formlabel">]]></HTML>
        <IfEqual>
            <Expr1><GetVar Name="OldValue#{Field}"/></Expr1>
            <Expr2><GetVar Name="NewValue#{Field}"/></Expr2>
        <Then>
            <GetVar Name="DisplayName#{Field}" HTMLEncode="TRUE" />
            <HTML><![CDATA[:</td><td class="formbody"> ]]></HTML>
            <GetVar Name="NewValue#{Field}" />
            <HTML><![CDATA[</td><td class="altvb">&nbsp;</td>]]></HTML>
        </Then>
        <Else>
            <GetVar Name="DisplayName#{Field}" HTMLEncode="TRUE" />
            <HTML><![CDATA[:</td><td class="formbody"><span class="edited">]]></HTML>
            <Limit Len="255" AutoHyperLinkNoEncoding="TRUE" MoreText="..."><GetVar Name="OldValue#{Field}" /></Limit>
            <HTML><![CDATA[</span> ]]></HTML><GetVar Name="NewValue#{Field}" />
            <HTML><![CDATA[</td><td class="altvb"><span class="editedicon">$Resources:Alerts_event_edited;</span></td>]]></HTML>
        </Else>
    </IfEqual>
    </Case>
    <Default>
    <HTML><![CDATA[
    <tr>
    <td class="formlabel">]]></HTML>
        <GetVar Name="DisplayName#{Field}" HTMLEncode="TRUE" />
        <HTML><![CDATA[:</td>
    <td class="formbody"> ]]></HTML>
        <GetVar Name="NewValue#{Field}" />          
        <HTML><![CDATA[&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="altvb">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>]]></HTML>       
    </Default>
    </Switch>
    </Fields>
    <Footer>
    <HTML><![CDATA[
    <tr>
    <td colspan=3 class="descriptiontext">]]></HTML>$ResourcesNoEncode:Alerts_event_lastmodified;<HTML><![CDATA[</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>]]></HTML>
    </Footer>
    </Immediate>
    </Format>
    <Properties>
        <ImmediateNotificationExcludedFields>ID;Author;Editor;Modified_x0020_By;Created_x0020_By;_UIVersionString;ContentType;TaskGroup;IsCurrent;Attachments;NumComments;</ImmediateNotificationExcludedFields>
        <DigestNotificationExcludedFields>ID;Author;Editor;Modified_x0020_By;Created_x0020_By;_UIVersionString;ContentType;TaskGroup;IsCurrent;Attachments;NumComments;</DigestNotificationExcludedFields>
    </Properties>
    <Filters IsVisible="True">
        <FilterDefinition>
            <FriendlyName>$Resources:Alerts_anything_filter_begin;$Resources:Alerts_post;$Resources:core,Alerts_anything_filter_end</FriendlyName>
            <ShortName>$Resources:Alerts_anything_filter_shortname;</ShortName>
            <Query>   
                <Neq>
                    <Value type="integer"><UserID /></Value><FieldRef name="Editor/New"/>
                </Neq>
            </Query>
        </FilterDefinition>
        <FilterDefinition>
            <FriendlyName>$Resources:Alerts_1_filter_begin;$Resources:Alerts_post;$Resources:Alerts_1_filter_end;</FriendlyName>
            <ShortName>$Resources:Alerts_1_filter_shortname;</ShortName>
            <Query>
                <And>
                    <Or>
                        <Eq>
                            <Value type="integer"><UserID /></Value><FieldRef name="Author/New"/>
                        </Eq>
                        <Eq>
                            <Value type="integer"><UserID /></Value><FieldRef name="Author/Old"/>
                        </Eq>
                    </Or>
                    <Neq>
                        <Value type="integer"><UserID /></Value><FieldRef name="Editor/New"/>
                    </Neq>
                </And>
            </Query>
        </FilterDefinition>
        <FilterDefinition>
            <FriendlyName>$Resources:Alerts_2_filter_begin;$Resources:Alerts_post;$Resources:Alerts_2_filter_end;</FriendlyName>
            <ShortName>$Resources:Alerts_2_filter_shortname;</ShortName>
            <Query>
                <And>
                    <Eq>
                        <Value type="integer"><UserID /></Value><FieldRef name="Editor/Old"/>
                    </Eq>
                    <Neq>
                        <Value type="integer"><UserID /></Value><FieldRef name="Editor/New"/>
                    </Neq>
                </And>
            </Query>
        </FilterDefinition>
    </Filters>
</AlertTemplate>
```

UPDATE

After this code - I made an attempt at changing the color on ALL of the alerts in alerttemplates.xml and updating. IISReset, and timer service restart | Fresh alert subscription - no modified alert.

UPDATE 2

Rebooted the physical server to no change as well.

UPDATE 3

It just came to my awareness that we have 2 different URL's set-up to access our SharePoint installation "http://companyweb/" and "http://sharepoint2010/" - Is this possibly related to the issue I am experiencing?

Answer (score 1):

Check the DB to make sure your edits make it into the DB:

Powershell:

```
    $contentService = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::ContentService
    $AlertsTemplateCollection =  new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAlertTemplateCollection($contentService)

    $DB = $AlertsTemplateCollection["SPAlertTemplateType.DiscussionBoard"]

    $DB.xml
```

That should look exactly like the alert template you customized in the xml file.

Then find one of the alerts you are testing:

```
   $w = get-spweb http://mysites.WhereIWork.com/sites/test_user
   $w.Alerts
   $A = $W.Alerts | Where-Object {$_.AlertTemplateName -like "SPAlertTemplateType.Disc*"}
```

Check the template that is applied to the alert

```
   $A[0]
```

Don't let the xml file distract you. The real test is what is in the database and what alert template is actually attached to the alert

I would not be surprised if there was a case where the alert template is ghosted and not referring back to the Alert Template. Also check your lists to see that they are referring to the correct alert template. If they are pointing somewhere else it will not help to delete and recreate the alert templates.